# How can non standard evaluation in subset lead to unanticipated consequences (=errors) when used as pure subset in functions?

Tags: r, subset

`subset` states

> For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions
> like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
> subset can have unanticipated consequences.

To me it is not clear, how this can lead to errors after reading [Advanced R - Non-standard evaluation in subset](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset). Assume I have the following code snippet:

```
myfun <- function(...) {
  ...
  df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", NA), col2 = 1:3, col3 = 11:13)
  df_s <- subset(x = df, subset = col1=="a", select = c(col1, col2))
  # In the following I only use df_s in some way
  return(...)
}
```

To me, this looks save to use in scripts / functions?

Minor issue: Can I include `row.names(df_s) <- NULL` in `subset` using `...`? I could figure that out...

Comment: This link was posted the other day, I found it quite useful: https://shipt.tech/https-shipt-tech-advanced-programming-and-non-standard-evaluation-with-dplyr-e043f89deb3d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is \`\[\` better than \`subset\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset)

Comment: @bretauv Thanks, this adds useful information and I didn't find this question. But I think it is not exactly my questions (see my edit): I mean I really only use the subset and things like `subscramble(mtcars, cyl == 4)` in your reference are even not possible. If I understand the ansewer there correctly, this should be save?

Comment: If you use it interactively (meaning that you apply it directly to your dataset), it should be safe. Problems starts arising when you use it in custom functions.

Comment: @bretauv I would say, `myfun` is a custom function. But things like passing an argument like `cyl == 4` to `myfun` is not possible.

Comment: To be a bit clearer, problems arrive when you try to pass the subsetting conditions as argument of a custom function. If you define a dataframe and write directly its condition inside a function, it's fine. But don't use subset if you want to create a custom function where users can pass whatever subsetting condition they want. I don't see a problem with the example in your post.

Comment: @bretauv Ok, in my case, subset is save. If you feel save, you can merge your comments to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning in the docs comes from the fact that `subset()` use non-standard evaluation, which makes it hard to use in custom functions when you want to pass custom subsetting conditions to a dataset. This is already addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset).

In your case however, you want to use `subset()` in a custom function but only to apply a known subsetting condition to a known dataset, not to pass custom conditions to `subset()`. There is no problem to evaluate `subset()` in this case.